# usage of break inside list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, break

```
list_rem_above = [(word,rem) word in keyword_list for corp in corpus_list if set(word).issubset(corp)]
```

Is there a way to incorporate break inside a list comprehension so that the below code can be written inside a list comprehension just like the one above. And is there a better way to exit from the loop instead of break which is computationally fast?

```
for word in keyword_list: 
    for corp in corpus_list:
        if set(word).issubset(corp):
            list_rem.append((word,corp))
            break
```

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `break` inside of comprehensions or generator expressions. However, with some clever usage of `itertools` you can still get the result you want with a comprehension or generator expression:

```py
from itertools import islice
list_rem = [
    (word, corp)
    for word in keyword_list
    for corp in islice(filter(set(word).issubset, corpus_list), 1)
]
```

Of course, the plain for loops are definitely more readable in this case, and almost certainly faster, too.

What your break statement achieves in your example code is to break after you find the first `corp` that fits the specified condition. So this code filters for that condition, and then slices it so you only take the first element matching that condition, or just continues onto the next `word` if there are no `corp` elements matching the condition.

Comment: There doesn't seem like there's any possible way this could be faster (which you've kind of noted).  If anything the generator wrappers will just add overhead and would undermine any native level optimizations that the comprehensions might use.  Still a good answer IMO.

Comment: @user120242 yep I totally agree. I guess this is useful if you wanted it as a lazy expression, but I'd still more likely recommend someone to define a generator, yielding each member.